# Creating single custom directive for ng-click to perform multiple controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I have the following code:

```html
<div>...
    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter ng-click="vm.add()" tabindex="1">
    <a href='' tabindex="2"><img id="touch" ng-click="vm.multiply(xyz)" 
    src="/ui/assets/images/xxx.png"/></a> 
    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"ng-click="vm.showId()" tabindex="1" title="Filter">
    </div>
..</div>
```

I want to create a custom single `ng-click` directive as its recommended for `div` (`ng-click` to be used for only buttons). I want to know if there is any way I can create a single directive for all 3 `ng-click` and call those 3 different functions in link at `$apply`?

Comment: You want a attribute-directive which does the same as ng-click? The question is, why? ng-click should work fine on div.

Comment: yes, i want attribute-directive as I have been suggested - Don't use ng-click except on buttons.  
If you have custom buttons(seen in few places) with <div> that uses ng-click,  a directive, have equivalent functionality (element.on('click', fn) ) to avoid ngtoucvh conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/psevypcs/2/

HTML

```
<div clicky="test()">test</div>
<div clicky="test2()">test2</div>
```

AngularJS-Controller

```
$scope.test = function(){
       alert('hy');
   };


$scope.test2 = function(){
       alert('hy2');
   };
```

AngularJS-Directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
        .directive('clicky', Clicky);

    function Clicky() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                clicky: '&'  // Take yourself as variable
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
               $(element).on('click', function(e) {
                  scope.clicky();
               });
            }
      };
    }
```

Comment: It may not be parent element always.. I have multiple clickable divs

Comment: Whats the use of it? We can directly call the ctrlr functions instead right?

Comment: You have to build in the logic, that the function is only be fired, if you click on the div you want. It should work like you wanted to. A own ng-click directive which is firing your desired function (different ones for each div). And you dont directly call them, it's a other scope where you call the test() function.

Comment: One observation - this makes my on click function xecution delayed. e.g.: if i click on test1, to show alert its taking 2 ms of delay. why is it so?

Comment: Can only be a browser issue (100tabs opened?) or other code, which runs into a delay.

Comment: no, not browser issue. It was fine when we used ng-click on divs. Hence wondering! let me try to dig in!

Comment: no, not browser issue. It was fine when we used ng-click on divs. Hence wondering! I dont know whats causing this slowness if directive is being used instead of ng-click

Comment: Got it!, forcing $apply speeded it up! - $(element).on('click', function(e) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            console.log("Hello..clicky..");
                            scope.clicky();
                        });
                    });