# Test directive attribute without template

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to run a few unit tests on an Angular directive which is restricted to an Attribute.  For now I'm only trying to ascertain that the directive exists.

Does anyone know how to test a directive that is an attribute only?

Here is a bare bones version of the **directive**

```
function ResetCustomer() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: (scope, elem) => {

      elem.bind('click', function() {
        //do stuff
      });
    }
  };
}

export default {
  name: 'resetCustomer',
  fn: ResetCustomer
};
```

...  the **HTML**

```
<a class="brand" reset-customer>
   <img src="path/to/image.jpg"/>
</a>
```

...and the **test**

```
describe('Unit: ResetCustomer', () => {

  let element, scope, compile;

  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('app');
    angular.mock.inject(($compile, $rootScope) => {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      compile = $compile;
      element = angular.element('<a reset-customer></a>');
      compile(element)(scope);
      scope.$digest();
    });
  });

  it('should exist', () => {
    expect(element).toBeDefined();
  }); 
});
```

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570189/creating-single-custom-directive-for-ng-click-to-perform-multiple-controller-fun/35570797#35570797

I wrote there a directive, not es6 but maybe it will help you

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to test the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to have a testable something on the directive.

For example in the callback have it assign a scope variable isClicked to true/false.

Then you can fire a .click in the test and have an assertion that isClicked should be true.

You can even go the extra mile and have a previous assertion that isClicked is false before you fire the click. I cant rmember what the method is called but 90% sure its .trigger('click') or mousedown...